# Is Streaming Video possible with Sql Filestream?

Tags: sql-server, streaming, filestream

We have stored all media in Sql Filestream, but now we'll need Video and Audio streaming... Will this be possible with Sql Filestream or will I have to take all of the Video and Audio out of the database?

Which technology would you use to enable Video/Audio Streaming?

- WebORB
- FluorineFX
- Wowza (way better I think than the first two)
- IIS Media (haven't looked into this yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **IIS Media** its **not possible** to store the data in a **SQL Fielstream**.

For further details check [**here**](http://forums.iis.net/t/1166406.aspx).

It's possibly very similar with the rest of your suggested solutions, since all of them need to re encode the material to enable streaming (if its not in the necessary format already).

You actually have **2 problems**:

1. **Re encoding the videos** into a format
   that enables you to stream it via
   the server platform you choose, just
   for this part you need to extract
   the files from the db since the
   encoding tools can't be fed from a
   database, even if its a SQL FileStream
2. **Store the encoded files**
   somewhere the media servers can
   access them, again they don't allow
   a SQL Server as a data soure, they
   probably have their own storing
   infrastructure or use the file
   system.

**Conclusion:**
The FileStream is extremely helpful when you have full control over server/client, but sadly not in your case.
You will probably have to **extract all files** from the DB.

Comment: But isn't the other way around possible? Stream something that's already in the database to a client? You can access the file using Win32 api, so I guess you can set up a stream? Don't see why they would call it filestream if this wasn't possible. 

Storing in the database would mean that you would first have to write the file to the disk, and afterwards store it in the database?

Comment: @Lieven - I extended my answer since it was too long for a comment

Comment: Re encoding won't be necessary since we will only have flv's in the database.

Comment: @Lieven - If you want to make use of these Media Servers you might **still need to re-encode** anyway (this is most likely the case), since even that they might use flash, they might want to have it in a special form + they have to add indexing and such.

Comment: Thx, ntziolis, for the usefull information. I'll update the question in the future with the chosen solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The FileTable feature in SQL Server "Denali" (not yet released) is designed specifically for this scenario (amongst others).

There's a good overview link here: [Using FileTables to Manage Unstructured FILESTREAM Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144%28SQL.110%29.aspx).

This will allow you to directly access and play these files through a provided UNC path without requiring any changes to the application, so you can use any of the above mentioned streaming servers.